# How to get Jenkins-Phabricator plugin to work?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, phabricator

I've just installed the Jenkins plugin to link it to Phabricator (https://github.com/uber/phabricator-jenkins-plugin).

I've done the step by step tutorial twice, but I still can't get Jenkins to comment in my phabricator to inform me on some Jenkins build plan.

I've manually tried to input the arguments ("Build with parameters" in Jenkins job), but I get this output log error :

[image]
How am I supposed to find a solution for this?
I do not understand the error : "No such build target".
Which phid am I supposed to input ? The diff, the revision, or the commit ?

If I do not input any PHID, but only the DIFF_ID, I get this error log : 
[image]

And also, I do not think the build is launched when I arc diff in my terminal, so I may be facing 2 problems, but I am not sure about this.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

My setup is slightly different, as I'm doing post-commit builds, and configured manually rather than using the plugin, but the parameters should be the same. In Harbormaster, I have:
`buildWithParameters?token=XXX&PHID=${target.phid}&COMMIT=${buildable.commit}`

The PHID parameter is the Harbormaster build, yours appear to be the Differential diff (which should be DIFF_ID if I am looking at the right docs). So I think you want:
`buildWithParameters?token=XXX&PHID=${target.phid}&DIFF_ID=${buildable.diff}`

The `token` is optional if you are not using the Build Root Token plugin.

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work. I tried with harbormaster build phid, but didn;t get anything better. Tried installing git plugins, but I seem to only get things getting worse and worse.

Comment: Am I supposed to have any git plugin running ? With whihc credentials? Phabricators, git, or jenkins?

Comment: I managed to go a little further in the process. I installed the git plugin, added credentials (username/password, for some unknown reason, no other method would work). But I am facing other problems now, I thank you for your help, it did help me in a way. The error log is now showing "Error from Harbormaster: #1062: Duplicate entry 'uri-znlgkHt4PGxO' for key 'key_artifact'"

Comment: This last message seems to be telling you that you have already sent some results back to Harbormaster, and are now trying to send some more results back using the same key. This may be because you are running the same test build again, in which case, starting a new test build might help. Or it may be something you have hardcoded that needs to be generated for each request.